# R Authentication error when looping search_tweets function (rtweet package) over vector of Twitter handles

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I've created a loop that runs through a vector of Twitter handles, and collects tweets from them using the `search_tweets` function from the `rtweet` package.

Downloading the latest version of rtweet

```
## install devtools package if it's not already
if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE)) {
install.packages("devtools")
}

## install dev version of rtweet from github
devtools::install_github("mkearney/rtweet")

library(rtweet)
```

Creating token

```
## autheticate via web browser
token=create_token(
app = "My_app",
consumer_key = "My Consumer Key",
consumer_secret = 
"My Secret Code",set_renv = FALSE)
```

Here are my my Twitter handles, stored in a vector

```
twitter_handles=c("@realDonaldTrump","@HillaryClinton","@MittRomney")
```

Then I loop through these handles, and store results of each handle as a unique dataframe

```
#Loop through the twitter handles & store the results as individual dataframes
for(handle in twitter_handles) {

  result <- search_tweets(handle, n = 3500 , include_rts = FALSE,retryonratelimit = TRUE)

if(length(result) != 0){

  result$`Twitter Handle` <- handle
  result$Source <- "Search"

  df_name <- paste(tolower(substring(handle, 2)),"_search")

  if(exists(df_name)) {
    assign(df_name, unique(rbind(get(df_name), result)))
  } else {
    assign(df_name, result)
  }
  }

  }
```

However when I do this, I get an error message

> Warning: 32 - Could not authenticate you.
>   Error in vector("list", ntimes) : invalid 'length' argument

However I don't think this is an authentication problem, because when I try with a random keyword/hashtag, I get results

```
data <- search_tweets("#rstats", n = 10, include_rts = FALSE,token = token)
```

My loop was working fine, but recently it has started throwing errors.
Any ideas on why this is happening, and whether there is a fix?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How are you creating your token? Are you using the `create_token` function? Or using the browser authentication?

Comment: I am using the create_token function

Comment: And you provide a credentials to your own app/token? i.e token <- create_token(
  app = "your app name",
  consumer_key = "your consumer key",
  consumer_secret = "your consumer secret?")? As outlined in the vignette? https://rtweet.info/articles/auth.html

Comment: Yes. I did exactly that. And the authentication worked fine.

Comment: I only ask because I cannot reproduce your warning message. What version of rtweet are you using? and httpuv?

Comment: Does the loop work fine for you? I'm not sure which version. How can I check that I have the latest?

Comment: Run `installed.packages()["rtweet",]` The version will appear in your output. Latest version is 0.6.7. You can also run `update.packages("rtweet")` to see if it needs updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### On the first error:

> "Warning: 32 - Could not authenticate you. Error in vector("list",
>   ntimes) : invalid 'length' argument"

in general, you'll encounter this error if you are using an older version of [rtweet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7).

Why?

When Twitter updates their API's, they sometimes change the structure of the API GET requests. [rtweet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7) has to reformat their requests each time this happens, requiring you to use the latest version of [rtweet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7) to maintain connectivity to the Twitter API. Interestingly, some API calls will still succeed as those calls to the Twitter API are unchanged.

The error you encountered is referenced @ [TwitterCommunity.com](https://twittercommunity.com/t/errors-message-could-not-authenticate-you-code-32/1223/13).

### Obtaining the latest version of [rtweet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7)

To obtain the latest version of [rtweet](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtweet/versions/0.6.7) you can use the [devtools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/index.html) package (after installing it).

```
## install devtools package if it's not already
if (!requireNamespace("devtools", quietly = TRUE)) {
  install.packages("devtools")
}

## install dev version of rtweet from github
devtools::install_github("mkearney/rtweet")

## load rtweet package
library(rtweet)
```

### Related Errors

> Error in vector("list", n.times) : invalid 'length' argument In
>   addition: Warning message: rate limit exceeded.

A good place to look for tracked errors is the Github package tracking list on github for the rtweet package.

- https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/issues/109

### Token Security

This is an aside comment but my sense is you may also want to share your complete code without your API keys. You can do this in R by using `~/.Reviron`.

```
# Reload .Renviron
# Do this to capture any edits to Environment variables
readRenviron("~/.Renviron")

# Generate a token
token <- create_token(
  app = "rtweet_51672443_test_application",
  consumer_key = Sys.getenv("RTWEET_CONSUMER_KEY"),
  consumer_secret = Sys.getenv("RTWEET_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY")
)
```

where .Renviron contains:

```
RTWEET_CONSUMER_KEY="<Insert Consumer Key obtained from Titter>"
RTWEET_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY="<Insert Consumer Secret Key obtained from Titter>"
```

I hope the above helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my version of retweet to the latest one. Still getting the same message `Warning 32 - Could not authenticate you.`

Comment: @Varun The recommendation on the thread at TwitterCommunity.com is to regenerate your application keys in that situation.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful inputs, Technophobe01